# Tools to work with definiteness

Tags: syntax, definiteness, indefinite-article, framework

I am planning to do a research paper in the definite articles of my dialect. Can anyone provide me with any framework that is suitable for analyzing the definite articles?

Comment: Can you give some more details on what you're going to do? You might want to look into formal semantics, I guess.

Comment: You need to be more specific. Irene Heim has written extensively on definiteness.

Comment: Here's a good article: http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/descriptions/

Comment: I want to discuss it from a syntax point of view. The articles we use in our langauge is a little pit different from the Standard ones.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend looking at systemic functional linguistics. SFL can offer a few different perspectives. At the syntax level, which SFL calls lexicogrammar, it would be useful to look at the use of the nominal group structure. At another level, which SFL calls discourse semantics, it would be useful to look at the system of reference e.g. https://books.google.com.au/books?id=9BqCtpYdeiwC&pg=PA34&lpg=PA34&dq=Systemic+Functional+Linguistics+tracking+definite+articles&source=bl&ots=2tfAH-_agz&sig=eIwNIcTpHcOqVgLegUT8bA1KvuI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj3263w-rfLAhVXwWMKHRE6B9QQ6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=Systemic%20Functional%20Linguistics%20tracking%20definite%20articles&f=false

Comment: The page is not shown by G.... books, can you insert here a small summary of what it says?

Answer (score 0):

For a starter, you may want to look at WALS http://wals.info/chapter/37 and references therein.